# Кнопка "тревога"

Tags: обсуждение

Хотелось бы прояснить, для чего нужна кнопка "тревога"? На профиле русский язык я нажал эту кнопку, чтобы обратить внимание модератора на ответ, который по сути не являлся ответом, а лишь комментарием. А получил ответ от модератора: "Свои жалобы на модераторов вы можете опубликовать на Мете"
 **Но ведь на модераторов я на жаловался.**

Надо ли в подобных случаях ( когда нужно просто удалить ответ, или аналогичный случай) сразу писать сюда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кнопка "тревога"  нужна для того, чтобы обратить внимание модераторов на тот или иной вопрос или ответ. В вашем случае вы видимо случайно  получили комментарий, который я написал под сообщением перед тем как его удалить. Или это у @Aer надо спрашивать.

Comment: Понятно, в любом случае на модераторов я не жаловался.

Comment: @Серж Я не давал подобных ответов, так что, видимо, случилась какая-то неполадка.

Comment: Там вашего имени не было.